# tail files in a directory without file name and header

Tags: tail

The following script works to cat all files in a directory without header but prints the file name. How can I cat without file name.

```
tail -n +2 * >> Compile
```

Comment: use `-q` flag: `tail -q -n+2 *`

Answer (score 9):

Alternative method:

```
for f in *; do tail -n +2 "$f" >> Compile; done
```

Answer (score 6):

sed can be used to miss out lines:

```
sed -s 1d * >> Compile
```

this is assuming the folder only contains test files though; I just checked here and it didn't like directories at all, while tail coped.

You could use find then though if needed:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f * | xargs sed -s 1d >> Compile
```

Added the `-s` Flag for separate. This deals with each file separately but *is GNU only* from the looks of things, unfortunately

Comment: Ah... one minute!

Comment: Oh dear.. I may get there eventually.. cheers for the corrections!